# Select all rows of predefined number of distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `User` table with the following rows

```
id: 1, favorite_id: 1
id: 2, favorite_id: 2
id: 3, favorite_id: 2
id: 4, favorite_id: 3
id: 5, favorite_id: 3
id: 6, favorite_id: 3
id: 7, favorite_id: 4
id: 8, favorite_id: 4
id: 9, favorite_id: 4
```

And looking for a query that return the first 3 distinct `favorite_id`s rows =>

```
id: 1, favorite_id: 1
id: 2, favorite_id: 2
id: 3, favorite_id: 2
id: 4, favorite_id: 3
id: 5, favorite_id: 3
id: 6, favorite_id: 3
```

Comment: Do you mean 1, 2, and 3?  If so, what do you mean by "first three"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff good question, I have an index for the favorites_id so the first 3 favorites ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can get first 3 unique favorite_id values in a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)
- Join this to the main table to get all corresponding rows.

Try:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM `User` t
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT favorite_id 
      FROM `User`
      ORDER BY favorite_id LIMIT 3) AS dt
    ON dt.favorite_id = t.favorite_id
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "first three", you mean the first three that appear by the ordering `id`, then

```
select u.*
from (select u.favorite_id, min(id) as min_id
      from users u
      group by u.favorite_id
      order by min_id asc
      limit 3
     ) f3 join
     users u
     on f3.favorite_id = u.favorite_id;
```

If you simply mean the three lowest values of `favorite_id`, then Madhur's solution is fine.